# VBA dynamic loop to populate column

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic

I am trying to populate each row of a column with 1 from the 2nd row after the header to the last row.
The column is "Ok to call" in a worksheet named Adults.
This code creates the column in the correct worksheet that I need but does not populate the rows with 1. I believe I have to add in the last row but don't know how. Appreciate any help!

```
Dim shtA As Worksheet
Set shtA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Adults")
Dim LastCol As Long
LastCol = shtA.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = shtA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

'Loop through heading row to get column number of "Ok to call?"
Dim okcall As Long
Dim a As Long
For a = 1 To LastCol
If LCase(shtA.Cells(1, a).Value) = "ok to call?" Then
 okcall = a
    Exit For 
End If
Next a
```

Comment: What do you want to populate the rows with?  You need to add a second loop after this one (you can use `a` again for the loop variable), with `shtA.Cells(a, okcall).Value = <something???>`

Comment: Yes! The second loop worked. I wanted the value "1". This is what I added: For a = 1 + 1 To lastRow shtA.Cells(a, okcall).Value = 1 Next a

Answer (score 0):

Added this after PeterT's suggestion:

```
For a = 1 + 1 To lastRow 
shtA.Cells(a, okcall).Value = 1 
Next a 
End
```